# Time-dependent manifolds

Tags: manifolds, physics, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying Classical Mechanics, and in some cases the particles in the study are constrained to move in a certain manifold, which changes with time.

I've looked for bibliography about time-depending manifolds, or something similar I could apply to this study, but I haven't found anything yet, 
so I'd greatly appreciate any bibliographical suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Any book dealing with non-autonomous differential equations (so pretty much any book) should fit the bill.  If you want better understanding of just manifolds Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds* is a reasonable choice.  For ODEs I would recommend *Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications* by Chicone (very theoretically rigorous and does most of its work in Banach Spaces).  For PDE, one text to consider is *Taylor's Partial Differential Equations: basic theory* (Springer).  If you want a treatment specifically in the language of manifolds, and taking a more differential geometry approach Pressley's *Elementary Differential Geometry* (Springer) is a pretty solid (and reasonably priced) introduction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have tried to review the bibliography that you recommend, but I have not found explicitly the question of time-depending manifolds, maybe because I don’t master the subject. Could you be more explicit about where I can find this? Maybe knowing the chapter or the section where the reference is I can succeed. Thank you very much again